# SSRS Report Time processing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report which is taking extremely long time to run. It is bringing around 187k rows and it takes around 5 minutes to run. When I checked the execution log table in Reportserver and I noticed that time processing is taking more compared to `TimeDataRetrieval` and Time Rendering.

Things I did to improve performance:

1. I made sure that keeptogether property of the report is False so that paging is allowed
2. The report is not doing any grouping or filtering or sorting. Everything is been taken care at database level.
3. Caching is not an option for this report, as the report has parameters and they are dynamic values.

Only thing I noticed in the report is for few columns, there are some expressions in the format, which cannot be removed as they are mandatory and was asked by my client. The report has few date columns and I was using following expression:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "RPL","M/d/yyyy","M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

I tried to run the report without the above expression, but I didn't notice any drastic change in performance

I also noticed that `TimeProcessing` for the report is not constant always. It keeps on changing. How can I make it to constant? Are there any other things I need to change or check to improve performance of the report?

Comment: What's the proc execution time compared to the reports?

Comment: Proc is taking around 60 to 70 seconds

Comment: Might want to look into this. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Also try this just incase " 
Had something similar happen yesterday. Alter your proc and add a return statement directly under the Alter statement and then f5. Then remove the return statement. Fixed my error yesterday"

Comment: Sometimes a better approach when trying creating different layout versions based on report parameters or render format is having 2 table or matrix versions and make visible the one is required, rather having only one evaluating format expressions for each record.

Comment: @Snowlockk - I think its not database related issue.Since most of time the report is waiting under Timeprocessing phase

Comment: @niktrs - I noticed that even by removing the format  expression from report,did not help me.It is still the same .When i looked in logs,I noticed that  SQLServer is waiting on the SSRS client to consume the data output with the wait type   async_network_io